# How to format multiple equations properly?

Tags: equations

When I specify a set of partial differential equations, I usually have to write out not only the equation itself, but also its domain.  To complete the problem, I need to specify the boundary conditions underneath it in the same fashion.  So the information I need to write is of the format:

EQUATIONS  in DOMAIN
CONDITIONS in BOUNDARY

Using simple `\[ ... \]` format, it looks absolutely horrible.  So I tried using a 2x2 array using `\begin{array}{cc}...\end{array},` but this doesn't look correct either.  What is the standard approach to formatting these equations?

Update:  This is what I have coded thus far:

```
 \[ \begin{array}{cc} -\nabla^2u=0, & \Omega\\u=g & \partial\Omega \end{array}\]
```

Comment: Could you provide a MWE (minimal working example) of what you have done?

Comment: take a look at the multi-line display structures in `amsmath` -- `texdoc amsmath` should bring up the manual if you're working with a tex live installation.

Comment: @azetina: good point!  I just updated my question with the code.

Comment: @barbarabeeton `\OT` In my MikTeX installation (Win 7) I have to command `texdoc amsldoc` (as the documentation is named `amsldoc.pdf`). `\endOT`

Comment: @Qrrbrbirlbel -- ah, okay.  i'm working on a (shared) linux installation (don't know which flavor of the os), and both `amsmath` and `amsldoc` pull up the same manual.  but you're right -- it's more reliable to use the exact name.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can probably use the `align` environment:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
     \begin{align*}
     -\nabla^2u&=0,\quad \Omega\\
     u&=g \quad \partial\Omega
     \end{align*} 

% alignat option added

     \begin{alignat*}{2}
       -\nabla^2u&=0,&\quad &\Omega\\
                u&=g &      &\partial\Omega
     \end{alignat*} 
\end{document}
```

For further reading about alignment, check [amsldoc](http://mirrors.ucr.ac.cr/CTAN/macros/latex/required/amslatex/math/amsldoc.pdf) under `Displayed equations`. About `\quad`, it is defined as:

```
\def\quad{\hskip 1em\relax}
```

Comment: Yes!  This was exactly what I was looking for!  Thank you so much, azetina!

Comment: Out of curiousity... What exactly does the command \quad do?

Comment: @Paul `\quad` is a space command equivalent to `1em`

Comment: Using `alignat` might be a better choice. This just happened to work great _only_ because the right hand side were of approximately equal width.

Comment: I know @PeterGrill It was not my intention to align vertically. It just happened to be. I will update my example with `alignat`.

Comment: Please @azetina how do I use the curly braces togehter with alignat?